# Setting up a localhost using IIS 7 for PHP 5.5.7

Tags: php, iis

I only have one folder at the moment and inside of the folder I have a `test.php` file with `phpinfo();` inside the file.

My folder that contains this is `inetpub>wwwroot>test.php` -- the typical setup.
I want to setup a page inside this folder that has all my errors and just name it `error.log`.

Would this be more beneficial or should I just check errors on a page-by-page basis? If anyone could give me some advice or maybe point me in the right direction for setting up a page in that folder called `error_log.txt`, it'd be great.

Comment: Just a curious passerby, but why are you using IIS to server php?

Comment: I just want to test out a few things using IIS, I know it's not the standard when using php.

Comment: OK.. php+iis is a nightmare. Enjoy testing :D

Comment: So i've heard, but I'm setting up an environment on my laptop at home, I've worked with PHP + IIS for a little over a year now but I'm curious on how i should set it up best at home.. i didn't set up our system at work.

Comment: Well, if you really want to install it natively on Windows, [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is probably your easiest and best bet. If you want something more robust, consider running linux in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) (or VMware Player, which is free, but not as robust as VirtualBox). You then have an "as-close-to-real-world-as-possible" sandbox.